# SQL view infers nullable column from non-null table?

Tags: sql, dbnull, sql-view

I have a Product table with non-null "quantity" (decimal) and "status" (int) columns, and I created a view on this table with the following case expression:

```
SELECT P.ProductTypeId,
       (CASE WHEN P.StatusId IN (5, 8) THEN 0 ELSE -P.Quantity END) AS Quantity,
       ...
FROM Product P
```

ProductTypeId is correctly inferred as non-null. However, the Quantity column of this view is inferred as nullable, even though the underlying columns are not nullable. This doesn't make any sense to me.

I could use ISNULL/COALESCE to provide a default value in this case and force non-nullability, but there is no meaningful default value, and this shouldn't happen in the first place from what I understand. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a view column NOT NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326813/how-to-make-a-view-column-not-null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The below explanation is for [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) in a table. I imagine the same applies to computed columns in a view.

> The Database Engine automatically
>   determines the nullability of computed
>   columns based on the expressions used.
>   The result of most expressions is
>   considered nullable even if only
>   nonnullable columns are present,
>   because possible underflows or
>   overflows will produce null results as
>   well. Use the COLUMNPROPERTY function
>   with the AllowsNull property to
>   investigate the nullability of any
>   computed column in a table. An
>   expression that is nullable can be
>   turned into a nonnullable one by
>   specifying ISNULL(check_expression,
>   constant), where the constant is a
>   nonnull value substituted for any null
>   result.

An example where your expression could return `NULL` is

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

WITH Product(Quantity,StatusId) As
(
SELECT -2147483648,1
)
SELECT (CASE WHEN P.StatusId IN (5, 8) THEN 0 ELSE -P.Quantity END) AS Quantity  
FROM Product P
```

Comment: And there's no way to specify that this overflow case is impossible?