# LINQ to SQL generate "null" instead of "not null" from sql server function "return table as"

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, nullable, dbml

I'm working with SQL Server Express 2012 with advance services and Visual Studio 2013 update 2. I have simplified the example to the core. I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Realty]
(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
...
...
[RankingBonus] [int] NOT NULL,
[Ranking]  AS ([Id]+[RankingBonus]) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
...
)
```

Having fulltext table function over this table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFilteredRealtyFulltext]
(@fulltextcriteria nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT 
realty.Id AS realtyId,
...
realty.Ranking, --THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR THE QUIESTION!
...,
( COALESCE(ftR.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftObec.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftOkres.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftpobvod.Rank,0)) AS FtRank

FROM realty
--these joins and where conditions are not important for this stackoverflow question
--this only shows why I use table function with return table
--it is because this is the only way I found how to generate LINQ to SQL with fulltext as IQueryable<T>
JOIN Category ON realty.CategoryId = Category.Id
LEFT JOIN ruian_cobce ON realty.cobceId = ruian_cobce.cobce_kod
LEFT JOIN ruian_obec ON realty.obecId = ruian_obec.obec_kod
LEFT JOIN okres ON realty.okresId = okres.okres_kod
LEFT JOIN ExternFile ON realty.Id = ExternFile.ForeignId AND ExternFile.IsMain = 1 AND ExternFile.ForeignTable = 5
INNER JOIN Person ON realty.OwnerId = Person.Id
Left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Realty, *, @fulltextcriteria) ftR ON realty.Id = ftR.[Key] 
Left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ruian_obec, *, @fulltextcriteria) ftObec ON realty.obecId = ftObec.[Key] 
Left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Okres, *, @fulltextcriteria) ftOkres ON realty.okresId = ftOkres.[Key]
Left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(pobvod, *, @fulltextcriteria) ftpobvod ON realty.pobvodId = ftpobvod.[Key]
WHERE Person.ConfirmStatus = 1
AND ( COALESCE(ftR.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftObec.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftOkres.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftpobvod.Rank,0))  > 0
)
GO
```

When I drop the function GetFilteredRealtyFulltext into DBML, the designer generate the column Ranking as **Nullable int**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Ranking", DbType="Int")]
public System.Nullable<int> Ranking
{
  get
  {
    return this._Ranking;
  }
  set
  {
    if ((this._Ranking != value))
    {
       this._Ranking = value;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect it should generate just **integer**:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Ranking", DbType="Int NOT NULL"")]
public int Ranking
{
  get
  {
    return this._Ranking;
  }
  set
  {
    if ((this._Ranking != value))
    {
       this._Ranking = value;
    }
  }
}
```

The table Realty is generated correctly in DBML file, the Ranking is just integer, but the table function is generated incorrectly. What is wrong with it?

UPDATE:

[Linked question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114260/why-sql-server-recognize-the-view-column-as-nullable-if-the-underlying-column-is) going to the core of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SQL Server considers the `Ranking` column from your `GetFilteredRealtyFulltext` function to be nullable even though the underlying table column is created as `NOT NULL`.  You can see this by running the following query against your database:

```
select 
o.name ObjectName,
c.name ColumnName,
c.is_nullable ColumnIsNullable
from 
sys.all_objects o 
inner join 
sys.all_columns c 
on 
o.object_id = c.object_id 
where 
o.[name] = 'GetFilteredRealtyFulltext'
```

I found that SQL Server does the same thing if you create a view based on Realty table.  Googling for an answer didn't find anything authoritative, but did lead to a [similar problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/how-can-i-help-sql-server-recognize-my-view-column-is-not-null-able) over at the Database Administrators site.  That led to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326813/how-to-make-a-view-column-not-null) SO discussion, which got me to try using `ISNULL`.  Using the `ISNULL` hack as in the following example gives the correct column definition in the DBML file, once I deleted the previous function from the DBML file and re-added it.

Is is needed to [force computed column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114260/why-is-a-not-null-computed-column-considered-nullable-in-a-view) NotNullable:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Realty]
(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
...
...
[RankingBonus] [int] NOT NULL,
[Ranking]  AS ISNULL([Id]+[RankingBonus], 0) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
...
)
```

And then force function to be not nullable too:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFilteredRealtyFulltext]
(@fulltextcriteria nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT 
realty.Id AS realtyId,
realty.RankingBonus,
ISNULL(realty.Ranking, 0) as Ranking  --ISNULL hack
FROM realty
)
GO
```