# Non nullable dummy column in Netezza View

Tags: view, netezza, notnull

How to create a non nullable dummy column in Netezza View. In the metadata of the view that column should show as notnull.

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW [VIEW_NAME] AS
SELECT CAST('01/01/9999' AS DATE) EFFV_DT;

For the above statement the view is creating properly but the metadata of the EFFV_DT column is showing as NULLABLE. But i want that as NOT NULLABLE.

Thanks

Comment: What error(s) are you getting when you attempt to do this? Please include the error message(s) so the community can examine and suggest possible solutions.

Comment: I'm unable to try this answer (so I won't mark as a duplicate), but see if this [SQL Server method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326813/how-to-make-a-view-column-not-null) works for you.

Comment: I tried this using ISNULL also like in SQL server but it is not working in Netezza.